# Why am I getting these artifacts in the middle of my circle rendered with WebGL?

Tags: javascript, shader, webgl, fragment-shader, antialiasing

I have the following fragment shader:

```
float curve(float theta) {
  float waveDepth = 0.70;
  float waveCount = 5.0;

  return waveDepth * (sin(theta * waveCount) + 1.0) * 0.5;
}

void main() { 
  vec2 cxy = 2.0 * v_pos - 1.0;
  float r = cxy.x * cxy.x + cxy.y * cxy.y;

  float theta = atan(cxy.y, cxy.x);
  r += curve(theta);

  float delta = fwidth(r);
  float alpha = 1.0 - smoothstep(1.0 - delta, 1.0 + delta, r);

  outputColor = vec4(1, 1, 0.5, 1) * alpha;
}
```

Which draws something that looks like this:

[image]

It's a wavy circle that looks like a star. I would like to get rid of the grey pixely artifacts in the center of the circle.

I notice that if I set `delta` equal to `0` (and avoid using `fwidth`), then I do not get these artifacts, but that *also* removes antialiasing from the outside.

Is there any way to keep the antialiasing but also remove these artifacts present in the center of the wavy circle?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ah, good call. I just realized that this is only happening when you draw a filled in grey semi-transparent antialiased circle in front of it with. I suppose it is bleeding through somehow?

Comment: Ok, got it. Had to `gl.enable(gl.BLEND);` `gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to ensure that alpha` is 1.0 when the fragment is near the center of the circle:

```c
void main() { 
    
    vec2 cxy = 2.0 * v_pos - 1.0;
    float r0 = cxy.x * cxy.x + cxy.y * cxy.y;
    
    float theta = atan(cxy.y, cxy.x);
    float r = r0 + curve(theta);
  
    float delta = fwidth(r);
    float alpha = 1.0 - step(0.1, r0) * smoothstep(1.0 - delta, 1.0 + delta, r);
  
    outputColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1) * alpha;
}
```